# Using Google API to store downloadable links

Tags: python, api

I was wondering if it is possible at all to store downloadable links on google sheets through the google api.

I can currently upload .npy files to google sheets but it converts it to one data point per cell. I would like to upload a file that other ppl can download as well, sort of like a pseudo database. Any tips or recommendations would be appreciated. Thanks!